# moving files from a folder into subfolders based on the prefix number with Linux

Tags: linux, bash, file, subdirectory, directory-structure

I'm relatively new to bash and I have tried multiples solutions that I could find here but none of them seem to be working in my case. It's pretty simple, I have a folder that looks like this:

```
- images/
   - 0_image_1.jpg
   - 0_image_2.jpg
   - 0_image_3.jpg
   - 1_image_1.jpg
   - 1_image_2.jpg
   - 1_image_3.jpg
```

and I would like to move these jpg files into subfolders based on the prefix number like so:

```
- images_0/
   - 0_image_1.jpg
   - 0_image_2.jpg
   - 0_image_3.jpg

- images_1/
   - 1_image_1.jpg
   - 1_image_2.jpg
   - 1_image_3.jpg
```

Is there a bash command that could do that in a simple way ?
Thank you

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: So far I've tried to use the below command => chmod +x move_files.sh
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417869/split-folder-into-subfolders-with-the-name-of-that-subfolder-dependent-on-file-n

Comment: @AlexMartin what is the context of the `move_files.sh` file?

Comment: Indeed, I thought it was generic command but that's not. I have been using the script from my link above and it's now working properly. Will close this now; thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
for src in *_*.jpg; do
  dest=images_${src%%_*}/
  echo mkdir -p "$dest"
  echo mv -- "$src" "$dest"
done
```

Remove both `echo`s if the output looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with `rename` a.k.a. `Perl rename`. It is extremely powerful and performant. Here's a command for your use case:

```
rename --dry-run -p '$_="images_" . substr($_,0,1) . "/" . $_'  ?_*jpg
```

Let's dissect that. At the right end, we specify we only want to work on files that start with a single character/digit before an underscore so we don't do damage trying to apply the command to files it wasn't meant for. Then `--dry-run` means it doesn't actually do anything, it just shows you what it would do - this is a very useful feature. Then `-p` which handily means *"create any necessary directories for me as you go"*. Then the meat of the command. It passes you the current filename in a variable called `$_` and we then need to create a new variable called `$_` to say what we want the file to be called. In this case we just want the word `images_` followed by the first digit of the existing filename and then a slash and the original name. Simples!

**Sample Output**

```
'0_image_1.jpg' would be renamed to 'images_0/0_image_1.jpg'
'0_image_2.jpg' would be renamed to 'images_0/0_image_2.jpg'
'1_image_3.jpg' would be renamed to 'images_1/1_image_3.jpg'
```

---

Remove the --dry-run and run again for real, if the output looks good.

Using `rename` has several benefits:

- that it will warn and avoid any conflicts if two files rename to the same thing,
- that it can rename across directories, creating any necessary intermediate directories on the way,
- that you can do a dry run first to test it,
- that you can use arbitrarily complex Perl code to specify the new name.

---

**Note**: On **macOS**, you can install `rename` using **homebrew**:

```
brew install rename
```

**Note**: On some Ones, `rename` is referred to as `prename` for `Perl rename`.